# HTML Video tag in Chrome fails to play intermittently against AWS ELB

Tags: html, google-chrome, amazon-web-services, video, amazon-elb

Our system uses an AWS Elastic Load Balancer.

We are encountering a maddening issue where our HTML video tags are failing to play randomly.  I can't reliably reproduce the issue unless I bypass the ELB, which makes me suspect it, naturally.

I've verified that the same files are on both of our IIS servers, and I have verified that the MIME types are the same on both.

The video files are H.264 MP4s, but they will sometimes work, so I don't think it has anything to do with Chrome's support of the codec.

Anybody have an idea on what I can do, or where to look next?

Comment: I guess this is a sessions issue. Can you enable Sticky Session son the ELB and then see if the issue still happens?

Comment: What does the HTML look like?  Is there an error message?

Comment: No.  No error, nothing on the console.  It just doesn't play.  I can inspect the element and open the url and it will download the mp4 file just fine.

Comment: does the request reach the IIS server, by confirmation of the IIS logs at the time of the request? What does the corresponding ELB log look like?

Comment: @error2007s. Dude, submit an answer so I can give you the points - Sticky Sessions seems to have done the trick.

Comment: @js3 Done I added the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a session issue on the AWS ELB. Enable the Sticky Sessions on the ELB and this issue will be resolved. Here is the developers guide.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-sticky-sessions.html

Answer (score 1):

I would enable full logging on both IIS and the ELBs, and carefully check the access logs on each to confirm.

You would expect to see a 200 http response code on the ELB and the IIS server for each request made.  Check for any requests that result in a 400 or 500 error. You need to pair each individual request from the ELB to the IIS server and review.

See [Monitor Your Load Balancer Using Elastic Load Balancing Access Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/access-log-collection.html)